# Sitecore Powershell Workflow State Name

Tags: powershell, sitecore

How do I retrieve the name of a workflow state for a content item, not the workflow state ID (guid)?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ("master:\content") -Recurse `
| Select-Object -First 10 -Property ItemPath, Name, "TemplateName", "Version", @{Label="Updated";Expression={$_.__Updated}}, @{Label="Workflow State"; Expression={$_._state}}, `
 @{Label="Published"; Expression={$_.__publish}}
```

I have see many examples of how to get the workflow state id, but I need the human-readable name of the workflow state for a particular item.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get the Workflow State Name by passing the item Id retrieved. This is because the workflow in raw values are stored as ID. This is why the ID of the workflow state is returned.

Using the below script, will return the name of the workflow state

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ("master:\content") -Recurse `
| Select-Object -First 10 -Property ItemPath, Name, "TemplateName", "Version", @{Label="Updated";Expression={$_.__Updated}}, @{Label="Workflow State"; Expression={(Get-Item master: -ID $_."__Workflow state").Name}}, `
 @{Label="Published"; Expression={$_.__publish}}
```

Note that I have tested this on a Sitecore v8.2 where the name of the workflow state is `__Workflow state`. You may need to update it accordingly as from your script, it is using of `_state`